# Ensuring Correlation Between Groups of Variables

Tags: r, correlation, normal-distribution, simulation

Correlation is usually defined between 2 variables - for example, height and weight measurements in athletes might be correlated, or height and salary might also be correlated.

Suppose I want to simulate some data with 5 variables such that:

- Var 1, Var 3, Var 4 are positively correlated (e.g. Var 1 and Var 3 have  rho = 0.7, Var 3 and Var 4 have rho = 0.6, Var 4 and Var 1 have rho = 0.8)
- Var 1, Var 2, Var 5 are negatively correlated (correlations are specified similarly)
- Var 1, Var 4, Var 5 are negatively correlated
- Var 3 and Var 5 are positively correlated
- Var 1 and Var 3 are negatively correlated
- Var 2 and Var 4 are negatively correlated

The basic way I thought of doing this would be to simulate multivariate normal data and try to specify pairwise correlation between variables:

```
library(mvtnorm)

    
n <- 5
A <- matrix(runif(n^2)*2-1, ncol=n) 
s <- t(A) %*% A
            

my_data = MASS::mvrnorm(100, mu = c(rnorm(5,10,1)), Sigma = s)
my_data = data.frame(my_data)
```

But if you look at the covariance matrix ("A" - I used a random covariance matrix just as a placeholder for this question):

```
         [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,] -0.2414465 -0.9779279 -0.9006928 -0.3163802  0.2882145
[2,]  0.1239762  0.8126305  0.6423246  0.4627432 -0.4384996
[3,]  0.4654360  0.5413073  0.6586486  0.8145828  0.9152730
[4,]  0.7416111 -0.2349908  0.3094658  0.3923940 -0.6832081
[5,]  0.1443405 -0.8119082 -0.7343444 -0.5168416 -0.1633220
```

Its unclear to me how you can take all your "correlation requirements" and enter them into this covariance matrix such that all requirements are respected.

Suppose we knew how much correlation we wanted between these sets of variables - would there be some way to "ensure" that this list of correlation requirements would be respected and be visible in the actual simulated data?

Thanks!

Comment: What does "Var 1, Var 3, Var 4 are positively correlated" mean? If it means that each pairwise correlation is positive how is that consistent with "Var 1, Var 4, Var 5 are negatively correlated"? 
Or in other words what correlation do you want between 1 and 4? 

And btw: Your example A is NOT a covariance matrix since it is not positive definite.

Comment: [Sylvester's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) can be helpful.  But the basic problem is that your conditions haven't been adequately quantified, since "positively" and "negatively" correlated cover a lot of ground.  You would be successful by setting all those correlations to really, really tiny values of the intended signs.

Comment: @ whuber: thank you for your reply! I made some updates to the question and I think I mighy have figured out how to do this for binomial random variables... I will post a new question!

Comment: Just edit this one, please.